# Unable to consume Create Order API endpoint through Angular

Tags: angular, api

I want to create order but I am unable to create order because of product ref in order mongoose schema so what to pass through function in order service so I can create the order. This is the code I wrote

**order api controller**

```
exports.orders_create_order = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.findById(req.body.productId)
        .then(product => {
            if (!product) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: "Product not found"
                });
            }
            const order = new Order({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                quantity: req.body.quantity,
                product: req.body.productId,
                orderDate: req.body.orderDate
            });
            return order.save();
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Order stored",
                createdOrder: {
                    _id: result._id,
                    product: result.product,
                    quantity: result.quantity,
                    orderDate: result.orderDate
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
};
```

**order.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }  from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class OrderService{
    product:any;
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    getOrders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get('orders', {headers:headers})
            .map(res =>res.json());
    }
    createOrder(product:object) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        headers.append('Accept','application/json');
        return this.http.post('orders',product,{headers:headers})
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

**create order function**

```
createorder() {
    this.orderservice.createOrder(this.product).subscribe(data=>{
        this.product=data.product;
    });
}
```

I am not getting what to pass through the function in service which is required by order controller to create order. Order schema have a product as a reference in it and quantity and date placed.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using ? what version of rxjs  ?

Comment: Angular core 5.0.0 and rxjs 5.5.2